# Softkeyboard android phonegap build issues

Tags: javascript, android, phonegap-build

I have a problem where the virtual keyboard is overlapping any input boxes in my app which is frustrating.

I finally figured out that you need to change the config.xml and add the following:

```
<preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="stateVisible|adjustResize" />
```

Now this works like a dream on android 4.2.2 but on 2.3.3 it shows the keyboard all the time, i only want the keyboard to show on input focus not all the time

**On a side not is it possible to specify  sdk verions for preferences**
e

```
<preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="stateVisible|adjustResize" sdkVersion="14+" />

<preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustResize" sdkVersion="14-" />
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the problem with a new project with recent versions of phonegap. Try to change

```
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
```

to

```
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
```

in config.xml. (not sure if you should keep your preference on softinputmode)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but in case it helps anybody, here is a workaround if you want to keep fullscreen set to true.

There is a phonegap build plugin called Keyboard which allows you to get the height of the keyboard when it appears.

```
<gap:plugin name="com.ionic.keyboard" version="1.0.3" />
```

This plugin works with a listener for when the keyboard opens.

If your textbox is at the bottom of the page set its containing div to absolute position, with a Bottom value of say `100px`. Then once the keyboard opens, the listener allows you to retrieve the height, which you can dynamically set a as a new Bottom css value to the containing div using Jquery: `.css("bottom", HeightofKeyboard)`.

On Blur of the `textbox` you can reset the `bottom value` back to `100px`.